# Can I create a Windows Junction (Symbolic Link) aliased to a Drive Letter?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, symbolic-link, mklink

I have a bunch of data files on an E:\ drive.
I'm moving all of that to a new computer and would like to consolidate many small drives (E, P) to one larger drive.

But I want all the programs referring to E:\ to "see" the files on V:
So I want to create **E:** that  links to say  *V:\OldE*

Can I use MkLink or similar like [Linkd utility](http://windowsitpro.com/storage/linkd-utility) in that way?
Perhaps I need to create a very small E:\ partition and then do an MkLink from E:\ to v:\oldE ?

(It seems like you can NOT do that, but I wanted to check)

Answer (score 4):

#### I want to create `E:` that links to say `V:\OldE`

If you no longer have a drive `E:` on the new computer you can use the `subst` command:

```
subst E: V:\OldE
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [subst](http://ss64.com/nt/subst.html) - Substitute a drive letter for a network or local path.

Comment: I have used that before, my understanding (and my distant recollection) is that subst does not work for ALL programs universally.  I have used that before,

Comment: @ClayNichols I don't know of any specific limitations, other than the recycle bin will no longer work (files are permanently deleted and not moved to the bin).

Answer (score -1):

winodows allows the use of the mklink with substituted drive letters., however, some apps don't like the symlink on a substitued drive, in my case I'm using phoenix platform and it forces me to use the actual drive letter instead of a subs letter, in my case the drive is **I:** and the subs letter is **W:**, phoenix comes up with the error message

```
** (File.Error) could not remove file "w:/ELIXIR/PROJECTS/hello/_build/dev/lib/hello/priv": not owner
```

so I'm forced to use the real drive letter with a kilometric path string

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Please keep the answers section to actual solutions to the problem.